# Apache VFS relative path

Tags: java, path, sftp, relative-path, apache-commons-vfs

I try to get folder's parent with Apache VFS using relative path, but I get "Invalid relative path"

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
FileSystemManager fileSystemManager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager
.resolveFile("sftp://myuser:mypassword@myhost/"); // works!!
FileObject root = fileObject.resolveFile("../"); // fails!!
FileObject fileObjects[] = root.getChildren();
...
```

I tried "/.." , "/../" as well, all got exception. What is the right way to the parent directory?

P.S #getParent will not work, It's for files only, not directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
        FileSystemManager fileSystemManager = VFS.getManager();
        FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager
                .resolveFile("sftp://user:password@host/",opts);

        FileObject temp = fileObject.resolveFile("/foo/faa/frog/");
        FileObject fileObjects[] = temp.getChildren();

        try {
            for (FileObject j : fileObjects) {

                System.out.println(j.getName().getBaseName());
                j.close();
            }
        } finally {
            fileObject.close();
            temp.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also verify if jcraft jsch library is in the class path.